# puppeteer on linux and windows give different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, puppeteer

Here is a difference between result pdf on windows and linux. When I'm trying to generate from linux images disappears.

That chart images source is dataUrl of canvas

Linux(WSL):
[image: linux pdf]

Windows:
[image: windows pdf]

> pdf render:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function printPDF() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no- sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080/new', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4', printBackground: true, path: __dirname+'/s.pdf' });

  await browser.close();
  return pdf
}
printPDF();
```

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do, what is expected and where it fails exactly

Comment: i think on linux it fails when trying to load javascript

Comment: maybe it is pdf-related issue. For example some pdf fonts or assets missing in linux

Comment: or maybe there are different settings on windows and linux machines and results simply mirror these differences in setup or infrastructure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is for sure a minor problem with a whitespace character in `--no- sandbox`

Should be `--no-sandbox`